# Data converted in some random string in webservice

Tags: php, json, web-services

I am creating a web service using PHP.
I am passing a some data in JSON format using POST/GET method.
I am passing data as below:

```
    WEBSERVICE_URL?data={
      "action":"facebook_contacts",
      "contacts":[
      {
        "uid" : 100007356270051,
        "pic" : "https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-prn2\/t5\/1118559_592238484_1133654491_s.jpg",
        "name" : "Smit Nebhwani"
      },
      {
        "uid" : 1289351411,
        "pic" : "https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-prn2\/t5\/1118043_1289351411_469744700_s.jpg",
        "name" : "Swetang Thakkar"
      },
      {
        "uid" : 1506453812,
        "pic" : "https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-ash2\/t5\/1118635_1506453812_1534707268_s.jpg",
        "name" : "Ravi M Maru"
      },
      {
        "uid" : 100004690921571,
        "pic" : "https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/static-ak\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yh\/r\/C5yt7Cqf3zU.jpg",
        "name" : "Qa Orig"
      },
      {
        "uid" : 100007093534387,
        "pic" : "https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/static-ak\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yh\/r\/C5yt7Cqf3zU.jpg",
        "name" : "Ru Kan"
      },
      {
        "uid" : 100007356270051,
        "pic" : "https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-ash2\/t5\/1076776_100007356270051_49934227_s.jpg",
        "name" : "Jonson Bool"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And In my web service when iterating in to `contact` array and converting it into associative array and trying to echo value of `uid` paramater for each. It echo as below:

```
1.0000352215999E+14
1289351411
1506453812
1.0000469092157E+14
1.0000709353439E+14
1.0000735627005E+14
```

Why numbers are converted like this?

Please guide me solve this issue.
Thank You In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `ini_set('precision', 20);` on top of your PHP script.

### The code..

```
<?php
echo 100007356270051;  //"prints" your erroneous value.. like 1.0000735627005E+14
echo "\n";
ini_set('precision', 20); // Set the precision here
echo 100007356270051; //"prints" 100007356270051
```

Comment: Does this solution guarantee no loss of precision? I thought that a very large number will be converted to `double`, and as such not all big integers can be represented. Better store explicitly as string...

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer. This will work "this time", but it will not work for slightly longer UIDs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert big ints to string before looping and showing.

```
json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to decode large integers as strings to avoid having them converted to floats in PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

This option is only available since PHP 5.4 though. For lower versions, you'd have to look for custom JSON decoders which support the same feature.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your numbers are not being *converted* : you are seeing a different *representation* of the number because they represent something that is too large to be an integer. Large numbers that need to be stored with "infinite precision" are probably best stored as strings - especially if they are an identifier (as in your case). I expect that you don't intend to treat them as a number (do math with them: add, multiply etc) - so don't store them as a number.

It has been pointed out in a couple of answers that there is a way to force this behavior in `json` with the `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` flag to the `json_decode` function.

**However** - slightly larger numbers than you used *would* be "converted" - namely, they would be converted to `double`, and in the process lose precision. Losing precision means that not all integer values above a certain size can be represented - and they will be "rounded" to a nearby value (that can be represented by a double).

Just to show what I mean about "loss of precision", here is a little test program:

```
<?php
$a=100007356270051000;
ini_set('precision', 22);
for($m = 0; $m < 3; $m++) {
  echo "m = $m\n";
  for($n = 0; $n < 5; $n++) {
    echo $a + $n."\n";
  }
  $a = $a * 10;
  echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Which gives the following output:

```
m = 0
100007356270051000
100007356270051001
100007356270051002
100007356270051003
100007356270051004

m = 1
1000073562700510000
1000073562700510001
1000073562700510002
1000073562700510003
1000073562700510004

m = 2
10000735627005100032
10000735627005100032
10000735627005100032
10000735627005100032
10000735627005100032
```

As you can see, numbers slightly larger than yours (just five more digits) can no longer be represented without loss of accuracy - when you add 1, the result doesn't change. This is because internally the number was converted to a `double` since it was too big to fit into an `int`.  This will happen silently and *will* cause you problems in the future.

> Beware the large integer - it is not as precise as you would like it too be.